# How do I use char* and std::string, interchangeably as well as in combination?

Tags: c++, string, char

I know a technical definition (`char*` is a pointer to a `char`, which behaves similarly to an `array`, and a `string` (literal) is an `array` of `char` as it is), but how do they *actually work*? I read through the section on it (most of the tutorial really) on cplusplus.com (but I clearly have to re-read some sections). Still, I tried some practical examples and encountered some frustrating situations.

1. I created a simple function, `void Log(std::string message) {std::cout << message << std::endl;}`, and that works great until I try to use it with `char*` in combination with `string`. For example, if I have `std::string a` and `char* b`, I cannot do `Log(a + b)`, but I *can* do `std::string print = “”; print += a; print += b; Log(print);` Why? How should I define my `Log(.)` function so that I can use it similarly to `Log(a+b)` regardless of what types they are (at least `std::string` and `char*`, but preferably also `int` and other types)? If that’s possible, at least.
2. When I do `char * a = “some text”;`, I get the warning `conversion from string literal to ‘char *’ is deprecated`. Obviously, this is not good, so why is this happening and how should I avoid this?
3. Under which circumstances should I prefer one over the other (apart from the obvious that I sometimes am forced because of some API’s, etc)? Is it a good practice, for example, to convert all my `char *` to `string` or vice-versa?

In general, my knowledge of `char *` and `strings` (and C++ in general) has… room for improvement, so feel free to give some sources for how to get more familiar and comfortable with `char *`, `strings`, and any other related types (`arrays`, etc?). Although, I would very much appreciate it if someone would explain to me the two particular points above, as well.

Comment: Forget online tutorials and pick up a C++ book. [Here are some that we recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Your question(s) above will be explained by its chapter(s) on strings.

Comment: `char * a = "some text"` is invalid. it should be `const char * a = "some text"`.

Comment: Are you confusing string literals (`"StringInQuotes"` is a literal) and `std::string`?

Comment: Also, there are 3 questions in one, each of which is a duplicate of a duplicate.

Comment: With regard to point 1, see: https://wandbox.org/permlink/TJ279e3NlsUve9yT

Comment: You are probably better off searching for help on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of cplusplus.com.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, if I have std::string a and char* b, I cannot do Log(a +
>   b)

No you can. Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void Log(std::string message) {std::cout << message << std::endl;}

int main() 
{
    std::string a( "Hello " );
    const char *b = "GreatName";

    Log( a + b );

    return 0;
}
```

Though it is better to declare the function like

```
void Log( const std::string &message );
```

For integral  types you should use the family of the functions `std::to_string`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void Log( const std::string &message ) { std::cout << message << std::endl; }

int main() 
{
    std::string a( "Hello " );
    int b = 10;

    Log( a + std::to_string( b ) );

    return 0;
}
```

> When I do char * a = “some text”;, I get the warning conversion from
>   string literal to ‘char *’ is deprecated.

String literals in C++ have types of constant character arrays. So you have to write

```
const char * a = “some text”;
```

> Under which circumstances should I prefer one over the other

In general especially when an argument is build from several objects you should always prefer to declare the corresponding parameter as having the type `std::string`.